# Allowing two libraries in jar to use two different versions of a dependency java

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, maven-shade-plugin

In our java project, we are using HBase 1.1.1 java APIs. This library internally needs to use Guava 15.0 (Earlier versions of HBase, for ex 0.98,  used Guava 18.0). Our current code base has one parent project and multiple child projects. A few of the child projects need methods only available in Guava 18.0. Is it possible for configuring the pom.xml of the parent project in our code base to let HBase use Guava 15.0 while letting the entire remaining code base to use Guava 18.0?

I've tried shading as shown below:
parent pom (example-parent)

```
<modules>
    <module>../example-child1</module>
    <module>../example-child2</module>
    .......
</modules>
```

child pom (example-child1)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>

<profiles>
<profile>
<id>child1</id>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>make-assembly-shade</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <relocations>
            <relocation>
            <pattern>com.google.guava</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.guava</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
            </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

And I built the jar using:

```
mvn clean compile package -Pchild1
```

However I am still seeing only one version of Guava in the final jar. Are there other ways to do the same?

Comment: Only if you run your application with multiple classloaders, like within an OSGi container or something like that. Doesn't sound like that's what you're doing though.

Comment: Depending on how all the component's use Guava objects, what you ask might not be possible even with multiple `ClassLoader`s.  Even if it were possible, I strongly recommend against it.  It would be best to make everything work with the same version of Guava.

Comment: When I have to do this (and I hate doing it) I usually combine the main jar and it's libraries as one fat jar then use a utility package (e.g. jar jar) to change the packages of the library making them effectively unreachable except to the classes inside the jar. It goes without saying you should only do this if all else fails

Comment: Could you run both 'parts' in separate processes and connect them with some remoting technology ?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest to define this 'special' guava dependency per profile. For example if Child1 requires Guava 15, in the related profile, add a dependency section with this specific one. If you want to keep thing simple you can remove it from parent and then decide on each profile (and group of modules) which version to include.